# I HAVE a main method in my class but Error: Main method not found in class / JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application

Tags: java, sql, javafx

Orignally, I tried running the following file

```
public class RoleDao {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("hello");
}

private static String dburl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/connectdb";
private static String user = "connectuser";
private static String password = "password123!@#";

//  method returns "role" type
public Role getRole(Integer roleId) {
    Role role = null;
    
    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    
    //exception handling
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dburl, user, password);
        
        String sql = "SELECT role_id, description FROM role WHERE role_id = ?";
        ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        ps.setInt(1, roleId); // for ? in sql statement
        
        //execute
        rs = ps.executeQuery();
        
        if (rs.next()) {
            int id = rs.getInt("role_id");
            String description = rs.getString(2);
            
            role = new Role(id, description);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally { // must no matter what
        if(conn != null) {
            try {
                conn.close();
            }catch(SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if(ps != null) {
            try {
                ps.close();
            }catch(SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if(rs != null) {
            try {
                rs.close();
            }catch(SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    
    return role;
}
```

}

by this in different package after importing it

```
package kr.or.connect.jdbcexam;

import kr.or.connect.jdbcexam.dao.*;
import kr.or.connect.jdbcexam.dto.Role;
public class JDBCtest1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RoleDao test = new RoleDao();
        Role role = test.getRole(102);
        System.out.println(role);
    }
}
```

However, it returns an error saying

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:602)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:340)
    at kr.or.connect.jdbcexam.dao.RoleDao.getRole(RoleDao.java:26)
    at kr.or.connect.jdbcexam.JDBCtest1.main(JDBCtest1.java:11)
null
```

So, I tried to run it in the very first file by main method added to **RoleDao** class

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
//      RoleDao r= new RoleDao();
//      Role role = r.getRole(102);
//      System.out.println(role);
        System.out.println("hello");
    }
```

but

```
Error: Main method not found in class kr.or.connect.jdbcexam.dto.Role, please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args)
or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application
```

Added to that, other file in this project folder refuses to update even after Save and Run

Does anyone notice a way to resolve any sql issues or main method/ JavaFX issues? I appreciate any help.

Comment: Check your classpath for the MySQL jdbc driver.  The java tutorial has lots of detail on classpath.  Add some of this detail to the question.

Comment: In the first error, as indicated in a previous comment, the error message indicates that the MySQL Driver class cannot be found. In the second error, the JVM is looking for a main method in the `Role` class, whereas you say you defined one in the `RoleDao` class. So you probably need to change your run config or the way you are running the application so that it is running `RoleDao`, not `Role`. Always read the error messages carefully.